# aChartEngine: getting coordinates of any point on the graph area

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am using achartengine to display line graphs.And i am stuck at trying to get the coordinates of a point on touch (not the coordinates on the line graph but anywhere in the graph area). so i think **getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(...)** wont help in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to post some code or example so we can help you

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no APIs to get a random touch point, but just the closest one on the graph.

Comment: @Dan I am able to get this done using androidplot but had to shift to achartengine because of the pinch zoom support.Can you tell me which would be a better option: trying to add pinchzoom to androidplot or messing with achartengine to get the coordinates?

Comment: I suggest you add a feature request on both of them. The fastest that gets your requirement done should win. For AChartEngine you can add it here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/list An extra note: I cannot suggest you use something else than AChartEngine and I have a good reason for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this code :

myXYPlot.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                displaycoordinates(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                displaycoordinates(event); 
                break;                  
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }           
    });              
}
```

where displaycoordinates() is defined below:

```
public void displaycoordinates(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    PointF point = new PointF(x,y);

    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    Double j = getXval(x);
    String xval = nf.format(j);

    Double k = getYval(y);
    String yval = nf.format(x);

    if(j>=condition1 && k>=condition2 && j<=condition3 && k<=condition4)
    {
        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xval+"xval"+yval+" yval", 0);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do the methods getXval and getYval come from? Could not find them anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the screen coordinates point then you can just call `chartView.toRealPoint()` in order to get the real data coordinate values.