# Achartengine: setClickListener() on x labels

Tags: android, achartengine

[image]

I  use Achartengine 1.1.0. Is posible to setClickListener() on x label's view? For exemple when i click "Dec" i want to show a toast: "December =14240"

Answer (score 1):

There is not any direct method to get the touch event on labels.

But by getting the touched position and implementing this, you can achieve what u want.

You will need to check that position touched is of ur label.

Then do what u want. 
To get the touched position see this

[aChartEngine: getting coordinates of any point on the graph area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566962/achartengine-getting-coordinates-of-any-point-on-the-graph-area)

Also u can use

```
    mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("X :" + mChartView.toRealPoint(0)[0]);
            System.out.println("Y :" + mChartView.toRealPoint(0)[1]);
        }
    });
```

and check x.y values for labels positions.